# Failed mysql date query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete, mysql-error-1054

I want to delete rows from a table that has a column more than 7200 secs old.

**The Query**

```
mysql_query("delete from logged where DATE_ADD ( log, INTERVAL $this->loginDuration SECOND) < NOW()",$this->link);
```

**where:**

```
name of table = logged; 
name of column = log; 
$this->loginDuration = 7200; 

The value of log in db: 2011-06-25 09:56:51.
Todays date and time [ Now() ] : 2011-07-05 11:39:02
```

The query is meant to delete the row with log value `2011-06-25 09:56:51` because it is older than 7200 seconds but it does not.

What am I not getting right?

Comment: its meant to delete but doesnt

Comment: assign your sql to a variable and print it to check for errors

Comment: can you see what query "delete from logged where DATE_ADD ( log, INTERVAL $this->loginDuration SECOND) < NOW()" this actually generates and try executing that?

Comment: this is the error msg: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( log, INTERVAL 7200 SECOND) < NOW()' at line 1

Comment: i am unable to reproduce your issue. but from the error message, it looks like there is some syntax error. were you able to resolve it? if not, can you paste the exact query being fired - for which this error message had come?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a space between `DATE_ADD` and the parenthesis: `( log, ...`.

Use `DATE_ADD( log, ...`

From [**MySQL docs, Functions and Operators :**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/functions.html)

> Note
>
> By default, there must be no
>   whitespace between a function name and
>   the parenthesis following it. This
>   helps the MySQL parser distinguish
>   between function calls and references
>   to tables or columns that happen to
>   have the same name as a function.
>   However, spaces around function
>   arguments are permitted.

And:

> You can tell the MySQL server to
>   accept spaces after function names by
>   starting it with the
>   [`--sql-mode=IGNORE_SPACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_sql-mode) option. (See [Section 5.1.6, “Server SQL Modes”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html).)
>   Individual client programs can request
>   this behavior by using the
>   `CLIENT_IGNORE_SPACE` option for
>   [mysql_real_connect()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-real-connect.html). In either case,
>   all function names become reserved
>   words.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to show you what I did (could not post this as a comment)

```
+----------------------+
| temp.d(table.column) |
+----------------------+
| 2011-07-05 22:08:20  |
| 2011-07-05 22:08:20  |
| 2011-07-05 22:08:21  |
| 2011-07-05 22:08:21  |
| 2011-07-05 22:08:22  |
| 2011-07-05 22:08:22  |
| 2011-07-05 22:08:23  |
| 2011-07-05 22:08:23  |
| 2011-07-05 22:08:24  |
| 2011-07-05 22:08:24  |
+----------------------+
```

10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

```
mysql> delete from temp where DATE_ADD(d, INTERVAL 1 SECOND) < NOW();
```

Query OK, 10 rows affected (0.01 sec)